# RHOSTUDIO : Not able to create a run configuration for a existing project

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

I have installed rho-studio and have imported my existing rhodes project into it.in order to run the project i need to create run configuration for the project.whenever i try to create a run configuration for the project (Run as => Run configuration => Rhomobile application => New) it does nothing.No dialog ever appears.However the same is working fine for newly created project from rhostudio.

please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved the problem by using one trick. below are the steps for the trick.

1)Create one rhodes application in rhostudio.("File => new => project => rhomobile aplication");

2)right click on the project and create run configuration ("Run as => Run Configurations")

3)In the "project name" field write the name of your existing project folder that you want to open and then click "run" button.

4)Now delete the rohdes application that you have created in step 1 and import your existing project into rhostudiio.

This way you can create a run configuration for your existing project in rhostudio.

Thanks,